# Parameterize a function including Rows in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my dataset:

```
case class CustomerStats(customerID: Integer, stat: Double)
```

Here is my current function :

```
def keepMaxStat(ds:Dataset[CustomerStats]) = {
    ds.groupByKey(_.customerID).
       reduceGroups( (x, y) => if (x.stat > y.stat) x else y )
}
```

But actually my case class is more like:

```
case class CustomerStats(customerID: Integer, stat1: Double, stat2: Double)
```

I am trying to parameterise my previous function like :

```
def keepMaxStat(ds:Dataset[CustomerStats], colName:String) = {
    ds.groupByKey(_.customerID).
       reduceGroups( (x, y) => if (x.colName > y.colName) x else y )
}
```

But I got that error :

> error: value colName is not a member of CustomerDateStats

How can I do that properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep  `CustomerStats` you'll have to control flow based on `colName` argument:

```
import scala.math.Ordering

def keepMaxStat(ds:Dataset[CustomerStats], colName:String) = {
  val ord = colName match {
    case "stat1" => Ordering.by[CustomerStats, Double](_.stat1)
    case "stat2" => Ordering.by[CustomerStats, Double](_.stat2)
  }
  ds.groupByKey(_.customerID).reduceGroups(
    ord.max(_, _)  
  )
}
```

or completely rewrite the function to take an ordering:

```
def keepMaxStat(ds:Dataset[CustomerStats], ord: Ordering[CustomerStats]) = {
  ds.groupByKey(_.customerID).reduceGroups(
    ord.max(_, _)  
  )
}

keepMaxStat(ds, Ordering.by[CustomerStats, Double](_.stat1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare `Rows` you should first convert `Dataset[CustomerStats]` to `Dataset[Row]` and then use correct `get*` accessor methods:

```
def keepMaxStat(ds:Dataset[CustomerStats], colName:String) = {
  ds.toDF.groupByKey(_.getAs[Integer]("customerID")).reduceGroups(
    (x, y) => if (x.getAs[Double](colName) > y.getAs[Double](colName)) x else y 
  )
}
```

Comment: that works indeed, though I didn't want to go back to DF, who efficient you reckon it is ?